# How do I find any space before "."

Tags: ruby, regex

I have names "example .png" and "example 2.png". I am trying to convert any space to "_" and any space before "." should be removed.

So far I am doing it like this:

```
file.gsub(" .",".").gsub(" ", "_").gsub(".tif", "")
```

Comment: Remember that `.` is a special character inside of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  an `rstrip`ped `File.basename(filename,File.extname(filename))` and replace spaces with underscores inside it then add an `extname`:

```
File.basename(filename,File.extname(filename)).rstrip.gsub(" ", "_") + File.extname(filename)
```

See the [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/4xZJU6)

*Details*:

- `File.basename(filename,File.extname(filename))` - get file name without extension
- `.rstrip` - remove whitespace before the extension
- `.gsub(" ", "_")` - replaces spaces (use `/\s+/` regex to remove any whitespaces) with underscores
- `File.extname(filename)` - a file extension.

If you prefer a regex way:

```
s = 'some example 2 .png'
puts s.gsub(/\s+(\.[^.]+\z)|\s/) { 
    Regexp.last_match(1) ?  
        Regexp.last_match(1) :
        "_"
}
```

([can be shortened](http://ideone.com/O5MpWb) to `s.gsub(/\s+(\.[^.]+\z)|\s/) { $1 || "_" }` (see [Jordan's remark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109728/how-do-i-find-any-space-before/39109867?noredirect=1#comment65568204_39109867))). 
See [this Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/wVdTFq).

Here, the pattern matches:

- `\s+(\.[^.]+\z)` - 1 or more whitespaces (`\s+`) before the extension (`\.[^.]+` - a dot followed with 1+ chars other than a dot before the end of string `\z`), while *capturing the extension into Group 1*
- `|` - or
- `\s`  - any other whitespace symbol (add `+` after it if you need to replace whole whitespace chunks with underscores).

In the `gsub` block, a check is performed to test Group 1, and if it matched, only the extension is inserted into the result. Else, a whitespace is replaced with an underscore.

Comment: More succinctly: `s.gsub(/.../) { $1 || "_" }`.

Comment: @Jordan: Yes, the logic stays the same: either Group 1 or - if it is not matched - use `_` replacement.

Comment: Yes... that's why I posted a comment to that effect.